# F# type inference needs type name but I don't know how to provide it

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I am an F# noob, so am struggling a bit getting some basic stuff to work. The context here is a FAKE build script.

I am trying to use the [AssemblyInfoFile](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/apidocs/fake-assemblyinfofile.html) namespace to generate an *AssemblyInfo.cs* without including a generated `internal` class. I know I need to call the `CreateCSharpAssemblyInfoWithConfig` function and pass through an `AssemblyInfoFileConfig` that turns off the `GenerateClass` property. I have this:

```
Target "Build" (fun _ ->
    CreateCSharpAssemblyInfoWithConfig (srcDir + "TestAssemblyInfo.cs")
        [Attribute.Version version
         Attribute.Configuration configuration]
        { GenerateClass = false }
)
```

But the compiler is complaining as follows:

> The type 'AssemblyInfoParams' is not compatible with the type 'AssemblyInfoFileConfig'.

At first I thought I just needed to provide the specific type to the compiler so that it didn't resolve to `AssemblyInfoParams`. However, I couldn't figure out how to do that inline so I instead tried this:

```
Target "Build" (fun _ ->
    let config : AssemblyInfoFileConfig = { GenerateClass = false }

    CreateCSharpAssemblyInfoWithConfig (srcDir + "TestAssemblyInfo.cs")
        [Attribute.Version version
         Attribute.Configuration configuration)]
        config
)
```

But now the compiler complains as follows:

> The type 'AssemblyInfoFileConfig' does not contain a field 'GenerateClass'

Looking at the definition of `AssemblyInfoFileConfig`, it clearly contains a *property* called `GenerateClass`:

```
type AssemblyInfoFileConfig
    (
      generateClass : bool,
      ?useNamespace : string ) =
        member x.GenerateClass = generateClass
        member x.UseNamespace =
            match useNamespace with
            | Some n -> n
            | None -> "System"
        static member Default = AssemblyInfoFileConfig(true)
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AssemblyInfoFileConfig` is not a record - it is a more standard type with a constructor.

You could just call it like this:

```
let config = AssemblyInfoFileConfig(false)
```